# MassTransit Create Request with Metadata

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit, clean-architecture

I use MassTransit package into my project (clean Architecture).

In API-layer I write custom authorization filter and in `HttpContext` exist my CurrentUserInfo data.

then I Need UserInfo inside the Application Layer where IConsumer exist like Code below.

Now which way is better to do:

- add metadata into my request client?
- declare general class and inject it into implemented IConsumer class.

```cs
public class OptionCreateConsumer : IConsumer<OptionCreateRequest>
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public OptionCreateConsumer(IMapper mapper, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest [following the guidance](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/mediator.html#middleware) in the documentation (assuming you're using mediator – which every time I hear "clean architecture" seems to come up.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson what is better really here? nice question, I'm also beginner.

Comment: As I'm not 100% sure if I got your questions right. But I would put all informations inside a message which are needed by a consumer to do a certain job. If the communication between your producer, msgqueue and consumer are not secure than you have a another general issue. So when you need userinformations inside your consumer put them in. If you have to put API level structures inside a message then something seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In the [scoped filter](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters) sample, you can see how Send/Publish and Consume filters are used to capture and pass a `Token` object from the request client to the consumer.

The `TokenActionFilter` is [added](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters/blob/master/src/WebApi/Startup.cs#L41) so that it is scoped as well, pulling the incoming data into the `Token` (which in your case, would be the `UserInfo` object.

The [filters](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters/blob/master/src/WebApi/Startup.cs#L32) configured for MassTransit are used to add that data to the headers, so that downstream consumers are able to use that header to initialize the Token (or UserInfo for your scenario).